# Paypal Multiple subscriptions Sample code

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

i have a website which sells several digital subscriptions (monthly, yearly).

Users may subscribe to many subscriptions and add them to his basket.

i am trying to implement payments of this basket using Paypal.

i succeded making things work for a single subscription but not for multiple subcriptions.

does anyone has a working sample code for multiple subscriptions ?

thanks a lot.
Dan

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own code from this site:
[PayPal Developer Standard Subscription Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/)
If you would prefer you can get code example for Express Checkout as well from the PayPal Wizard. [PayPal Wizard Code Examples](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/)
Here is another option for you. Here is a basic code example for a PayPal Subscription Button with drop down menus:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Sample Subscription Button">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Multiple Options">Multiple Options</td>  </tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="Example Monthly">Example Monthly : $20.00 USD - monthly</option>
<option value="Example Daily">Example Daily : $5.00 USD - daily</option>
<option value="Example Annual">Example Annual : $125.00 USD - yearly</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Example Monthly">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="20.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_period0" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="option_frequency0" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Example Daily">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_period1" value="D">
<input type="hidden" name="option_frequency1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Example Annual">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="125.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_period2" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name="option_frequency2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btnbtn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
   </form>
```

This is an example of an open source code button.